# How do I correct the preview image aspect ratio in the desktop display?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, image-viewers

See the included images. On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, images shown on the desktop are horizontally stretched. I am using a 4k built-in screen scaled to 200% with no external monitors.

On the desktop:
[image]

In the file explorer (note the aspect ratio is correct here):
[image]

Unfortunately I don't know enough about Nautilus / Ubuntu to search for the right keywords, since I haven't found links to this issue elsewhere. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Just upgraded to 20.10 and can confirm the issue still exists.

Comment: I have the same problem in 20.04!